# how to execute python script on atom on windows

Tags: python

I am using Atom on Windows 10. While setting up Atom on my computer, I created a folder called "beyond basics". Then I created a python file. I installed platform io on Atom. i got a "+" icon on screen. upon clicking that i got a command line. I am trying to execute on that by writing `python filename` but I am getting an error. Any help is appreciated.

`python3 myfile.py`

[image]

Comment: According to picture, content in your file is not saved. Everythin should work, you just didn't save your code yet.

Comment: thanks. that was the problem i wasnot saving my work. thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `myfile.py` without the `python` prefix. It may work, as it works for me on Windows 10. Your bubble is covering up an error message that could help use debug. Can you add an edit and tell us the error message? Until then, just try the command without the python prefix.

You should also save before running, as was commented by Denis Fetinin.

If it still doesn't work, try addding python to the env variables. It's a simple process that you can follow [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/).

Comment: didn't work :(  i think path is there because my python works fine when executed from cmd

Comment: There is really nothing wrong with executing it from the CMD. I'm not really an atom expert, but make sure it is up to date, and if you can't find anything just run it from the command line. Also, having (briefly) used atom, I fully recommend using IDLE, as it seems to work just as well without anything like this.